# Script for opening up a Google search in a browser

Tags: python

I'm a programming novice whose experience is limited to writing very simple programs in Python. For part of my first 'real' project I'd like to write a script that takes an input and opens up a browser window with a Google search for that input. I'm at sea on how to accomplish this; I've fiddled around with variations on scripts like [this](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/), but this outputs the results by printing it to the console; for my purposes, I'd like the output to actually open a window with the search results for the query (ultimately I'd also like the script to take screenshot of the browser window and paste it to a Word document, but one thing at a time).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Opening a webpage is pretty simple in Python.

```
import webbrowser
url = "https://www.google.com.tr/search?q={}".format(search_term)    
webbrowser.open(url)
```

For a little more reliability, you can pass search_term to [`urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) first.